# ActiveMQ - strategy for only publishing data for which there are interested subscribers?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, messaging, publish-subscribe, messagebroker

I have a message broker to which various clients will connect over the course of the day for short periods of time.

The broker maintains a topic on which it can publish prices for thousands of things but at any given time the set of currently connected clients will only be interested in a small subset of these things.

In a tightly coupled system clients would explicitly subscribe for particular things and the server would keep track of low level client connect/disconnect events (automatically unsubscribing disconnected clients) and only publish prices for things for which clients are subscribed.

What is the best approach for handling this kind of thing in the more loosely coupled world of messaging systems like ActiveMQ?

In my case the broker has to minimise the number of things for which it publishes prices as it gets its prices from a third party system that imposes a hard constraint on the number of things for which prices can be streamed at any given time.

My first inclination is not to try and track low level events, that tell the broker who's currently connected, and not to require clients to explicitly signal that they're no longer interested in prices for particular items.

Instead clients would regularly announce their interest in prices for a given set of items. The broker would publish prices for anything for which there was active interest - and eventually stop publishing prices for things for which no client had announced any recent interest.

So unlike a more tightly coupled system clients would, every so often, have to re-announce their interest in the given set of things for which they want prices but never actively have to announce an end in interest.

Are there better or more standard/accepted approaches to this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

your producer need to be aware of consumers connected and their selectors if any, so i think :

1- he need to maintain a list of selectors to know what to publish and for this reason you need to maintain this list by using advisory-message http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

```
AdvisorySupport.getConsumerAdvisoryTopic()
```

2- Consumers on startup sends a message to producer to inform it in what informations their are interested and maybe which destination to use if you want different destinations, and notify unsubscribing or stopping interest.

3- simply keep the Fire-and-Forget EIP pattern